# SharePoint site and relative url issue

Tags: site-collection, site, web, root

I have set one image as a background image in SharePoint Master page.

So here issue I am facing is in displaying this image in my non-root site collection.This works perfectly in my root site collection.

I am using a relative path to the library to display image ex. `/Images/coffeebean.jpg`.

By using developer tools I came to know that hovering on that relative path image it shows the path from the root site collection.

```
http://SITECOLLECTION/Images/coffeebean.jpg
```

instead of

```
http://SITECOLLECTION/sites/test/Images/coffeebean.jpg
```

I don't want to use absolute URL.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can insert an image in a SharePoint master page. Both of them are relative url.

**14 Hive (Physically hosted):** You can place your images physically in the 14 hive folder under `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES`

Place a image here (logo.png) and you can access this image in your masterpage like this

```
<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/logo.png" runat="server"/>
```

**Site Collection (Library hosted)** Upload the logo.png file in any document library on your site collection. If your library name is "Images" here is how you can access the image.

```
<img src="../../Images/logo.png" />
```

Both the approaches are fine depending on your portability requirement of the site.

Check the below MSDN links  for reference

[Understanding Absolute and Relative URL Addresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208688(v=office.12).aspx)

[Good practice for image URLs](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/urls-and-tokens-in-sharepoint)

MSDN Forum link [Adding relative image in master page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5150f4e6-aa2c-43b5-a0fe-ceeaee167355/adding-relative-image-in-master-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)